# Cannot connect to SharePoint 2010 Web Site whilst on the server locally - Access denied

Tags: sharepoint-2010

I am getting the error below while getting the Search Crawlers to work:-

***The start address sts4://mysites/contentdbid={3d198865-7f27-4633-bd71-902795032d78} cannot be crawled.***

***Context: Application 'Search_index_file_on_the_search_server', Catalog 'Search'***

***Details:
Access is denied. Verify that either the Default Content Access Account has access to this repository, or add a crawl rule to crawl this repository. If the repository being crawled is a SharePoint repository, verify that the account you are using has "Full Read" permissions on the SharePoint Web Application being crawled. (0x80041205)***

I have checked all permissions and they appear to be in order.

While investigating this problem I discovered that when I RDP to the SharePoint server and connect to the sites whilst on the server (locally to the server) I get access denied.

The Central Administration works just fine, but all the other Web Applications (intranet & mysites) will not allow me to login. I get prompted to enter username and password (like I do when connecting to CA) but it never accepts the login. These sites work without any problems when accessed from client workstations.

When I check the site log file it is reporting a http 401 Unauthorised error.

Note: The sites are not using Claims Authentication

Any ideas on how to fix this?

Thanks,
Andrew

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're probably having the loopback issue problem. Follow instructions in this KB article: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/896861